# How to get cw20 token details from terra.js

Tags: web3js

I can get cw20 token balance using this code snippet

```
const response = await terraConfig.wasm.contractQuery(tokenAddress, {
  balance: { address: walletAddress },
});
```

how can I get the token details like name, symbol and decimals details using terra.js